# Why XSD date type consider YYYYY-MM-DD as a valid date?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an XSD with the following element

`<element name="fromDate" type="date" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />`

And I have an XML with the following element

`<fromDate>20100-11-22</fromDate>`

If I validate that XML against the above XSD, it gives no errors and takes 20100-11-22 as a valid date. Why is this happening? How to force it to check for YYYY instead of taking YYYYY also as valid?

**Update**

Upon further reading, found out that according to W3C specs lexical representation on date time allows "four-or-more digit optionally negative-signed numeral that represents the year" [1].

[1] https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-lexical-representation

Comment: Last century did you feel that YY was sufficient to represent the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `xs:pattern` to restrict the number of year digits to four, if you don't care about a Y2K-like problem in the year 10,000:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ShortSightedDate">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
    <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: If you want to be even more shortsighted, you could use the `minExclusive` and `maxExclusive` facets to restrict the range, say, to dates between 2010 and 2030.